# concatenating files using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have many text files with extension .txt each having three columns and i want to concatenate all one below another with '>>>>>' symbol in between and want to save it in another text file
Input:

```
file1.txt         file2.txt      file3.txt    
1.2 2.0 3.0       2.0 3.2 4.1    2.1  4.0  6.3
3.5 4.5 5.3       4.1 6.2 8.2    1.2  4.3  2.3
3.1 4.4 5.7       2.3 5.6 9.0    2.6  4.2  4.1
```

output:

```
>>>>>
1.2 2.0 3.0
3.5 4.5 5.3
3.1 4.4 5.7
>>>>>
2.0 3.2 4.1
4.1 6.2 8.2
2.3 5.6 9.0
>>>>>
2.1 4.0 6.3
1.2 4.3 2.3
2.6 4.2 4.1
```

i tried

```
import nump as np
import pandas as pd
data=np.loadtxt("file*.txt")
conc= np.concatenate(data)
np.savetxt('output',conc)
```

but it doesnot solve my problem.I hope experts may help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pandas solution covering concatenation of multiple CSV/text files with same or different columns is covered here: https://blog.softhints.com/how-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-with-python/. You can use single line for Linux or tracing data by file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `pandas` or `numpy`. They are not intended for text manipulation in general. You can try the following, which uses `glob` to detect files with a pattern (e.g. `file*.txt`).

```py
import glob

with open('output.txt', 'w') as g:
    for filename in glob.glob('file*.txt'):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            g.write('>>>>\n')
            g.write(f.read())
```

If you happen to use shell (such as bash), then it might be more natural to use a shell script, something like:

```sh
for f in file*.txt
do
  printf '>>>>\n' >> output.txt
  cat "$f" >> output.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use numpy for these kinds of problems. You can use `glob` from `pathlib.Path` as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path 
content = ''
for file  in Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
  content += '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n'
  with open(file) as f:
    content += f.read()

with open('out.txt', 'w+') as f:
  f.write(content)
```

Comment: To save memory, you could open two file handles and write directly to output, without creating `content`. Also, you should specify the read mode of the input file handle.

Comment: @Alex thanks that's a great advice. Regarding the read mode, however, it is the default option for the open function so it is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Given limited context:

```
input_files=['text1.txt','text2.txt','text3.txt']
file_out=open('output.txt',mode='a')
for files in input_files:
    loaded_file=open(files).read()
    file_out.write(loaded_file)
    file_out.write('\n<<<<<')
```

EDIT:
However if these are arrays and you're planning on doing something with them you might want to load them as pandas csv create a column called 'text_file' and use that to help you reference

```
import pandas as pd
input_files=['text1.txt','text2.txt','text3.txt']
df=pd.Dataframe(columns=[...])
for files in input_files:
    data=pd.read_csv(files)
    data['where from']=files
    df=pd.append(df,data)
pd.write_csv(df)
```